# Start recording as soon as the user starts speaking in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, silverlight-4.0

I just wanted to know if there is a way to start recording from the microphone as soon as the user starts speaking.

I know how to record audio from the microphone using the normal steps, but it always requires the user to start the recording himself by pressing a button or something.

I wanted to know if there is an event that can trigger recording when the user starts to speak. Or if I can make the program understand when the user is speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this can't be done in WP7 at a system level. As for your own app - in theory it is possible. You could start the mic, and perform a mic buffer analysis each time the buffer ready event is raised. You would analyze the sound pattern, apply some separate-voice-from-noise algorith (if one exists in pure .net implementation) and, if voice is detected, start sending the data to a recording stream. It is a great overhead for a device though.

Windows 7 has voice activated commands already. I would recommend waiting for a few more update releases for WP7, most likely Microsoft is to roll our a feature like this soon. Although it would still drain power, since the system would need to have a mic running all the time, and do a wave-sequence analysis.

Comment: i would say, this is a more detailed Answer. But i do think they should research more on policy's, this would go against user experience by the terms of the Windows marketplace.Should he/she not try it? well that's ultimately up to him/her.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for your answer. So basically I have to start the mic as soon as the application starts and do some kinds of speech recognition on each buffer I get from the mic. Is there an easy way to do this?
All I get from the mic is an array of bytes depending on the sample rate, the buffer duration and the number of channels. Can I perform some kind of operations on this array of bytes to know whether it has speech or not, and I would be grateful if you can give me a head start in this, as I don't have any experience in it.